# How to rotate a THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry with THREE.WaterShader and MirrorMesh

Tags: rotation, three.js, shader

In [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_shaders_ocean) we  have a THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry with WaterShader and Water Normals texture. If you try to delete the rotation at line 119, the plane rotates as expected but the Shader and the normals aren't working correct anymore but they are distorted.

How can you rotate without distortion?Is it something to be changed at the WaterShader.js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem.. As I thought there is something to be changed at the WaterShader.js file. At the vertexShader (line 24) you need to change the line 34 from :

```
worldPosition = mirrorCoord.xyz
```

to

```
worldPosition = mirrorCoord.xzy
```

and the problem is solved!